# Search full device for magic number as hex

Tags: linux, devices, luks

I am currently trying to solve a forensic file hunt training question.

There were hints given, that there is a LUKS container and that we need to find the LUKS header in order to go on with the next training question.

From the information given along with the question, the header can be identified with this magic number
(hex) 4c554b53babe
I am now searching the full device for this magic number.

To do so, I started with

`xxd -g0 -c 32 /mnt/luksTraining/training001.dd | grep -C 1 4c554b53babe`

But then realized, that this only works when the header is not split into two lines. For example the first half of the header is in the very end of a line, and the other half in the following line.

Is there a "smart" way to search for a specific file header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a "smart" way to search for a specific file header?

Basically you are searching for a specific bytestring, so it would best to search the binary data directly instead of `xxd` output, which can produce false negatives (as well as potential false positives), i.e with:

```
grep -oba "$(printf '\x4c\x55\x4b\x53\xba\xbe')" /mnt/luksTraining/training001.dd
```

The above will output the byte offset in training001.dd where the given bytestring is located.

More ways to grep bytestrings described in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319878/using-grep-to-search-for-hex-strings-in-a-file).

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. It is not very fast, but I do not care about this for now

Answer (score 0):

A few off-hand thoughts; none will be fast...

- Open the device as a binary file and use a regex (for example with python)
- Iterate over the `xxd` output with a shell loop using its `-len` and `-seek` options to change the search start point to be every byte